# How can I write a script that checks whether an image node is connected a color input or a non color input?

Tags: scripting, shader-nodes, color-management

So i tried using chatgpt for this which is why I'm here XD
I saw this free tool blender bob on youtube had made that would change color space of image nodes based on whether it had a particular keyword or not. While great for PBR materials, my project is using duplicates of a single image to drive the color and drive the roughness, bump, etc. So I will have to create multiple duplicates of the image, assign them the keywords and then replace all the images in the nodes. I figured why dont i just alter the script so that it detects what kind of input its connected to and change the color space that way. But chat GPT cant figure it out, and I obviously cant :P
any suggestion to how can i do this, attaching the script chatgpt made below:

```
    import bpy
from bpy.types import Image, Operator, Panel, ShaderNodeTree

class FixColorSpaceBase:
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    # Must replace these with the color space names you want to use
    color_space: str
    non_color_space: str

    def set_color_space(self, image: Image, is_color: bool):
        """Set the color space of an image based on whether it is connected to a color input or not."""
        if is_color:
            image.colorspace_settings.name = self.color_space
        else:
            image.colorspace_settings.name = self.non_color_space

    def find_image_nodes(self, node_tree: ShaderNodeTree):
        """Find all image nodes in a node tree and set their color space. If a group node is found explore its node tree recursively."""
        for node in node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE' and node.image:
                is_color = False
                for input in node.inputs:
                    if input.name in ['Color', 'Base Color']:
                        is_color = input.is_linked
                        break
                self.set_color_space(node.image, is_color)
            elif node.type == 'GROUP':
                self.find_image_nodes(node.node_tree)

    def execute(self, _context):
        # Set color space for images in all materials
        for material in bpy.data.materials:
            if material.node_tree:
                self.find_image_nodes(material.node_tree)
        
        # Set color space for images in all worlds
        for world in bpy.data.worlds:
            if world.node_tree:
                self.find_image_nodes(world.node_tree)
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the following code will add a "Check Where Links Go" operator to your <kbd>F3</kbd> menu. Running it will display in system console what types of sockets the links lead to (the operator will be only available if you're in the shading editor and have the Image Texture selected).

```py
import bpy

the_id = "check_where_links_go"


class CheckWhereLinksGo(bpy.types.Operator):
    """List the socket types of the links from Image Texture Color"""
    bl_idname = f"object.{the_id}"
    bl_label = "Check Where Links Go"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        if not context.active_node:
            return False
        return context.active_node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE'

    def execute(self, context):
        node = context.active_node
        socket_types = {l.to_socket.type for l in node.outputs['Color'].links}
        print("This Image Texture Node is linked to sockets of these types:")
        print(*socket_types, sep="\n")
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(CheckWhereLinksGo.bl_idname, text=CheckWhereLinksGo.bl_label)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CheckWhereLinksGo)
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_view.append(menu_func)
    setattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_cls", CheckWhereLinksGo)
    setattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_fun", menu_func)


def unregister():
    oldclass = getattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_cls")
    oldfunc = getattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_fun")
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(oldclass)
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_view.remove(oldfunc)
    delattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_cls")
    delattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_fun")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        unregister()
    except AttributeError:
        register()
```

[image]

This is mostly boilerplate code, and could be shortened to a oneliner:

`C.area.type='NODE_EDITOR';n=C.active_node;C.area.type='CONSOLE';print(*{l.to_socket.type for l in n.outputs[0].links})`

Which you would use by going to your Shader Editor, selecting the Image Texture node, pressing <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>, pasting this code and pressing <kbd>↩ Enter</kbd>:

[image]

I tested both techniques on Blenders 3.0 and 3.5.

Comment: for some reason it does nothing in my version of blender, theres no output in the console either

Comment: @VisuaLHippocracY Do you understand the difference between Python console and System console? How about the "oneliner", did you try to test it, didn't it display something in the Python console?

Comment: whoops my bad, yes it does print it out. however how can i change it so that it detects all the nodes, active and inactive, throughout the file that are connected to an rgba input?

Comment: @VisuaLHippocracY by iterating over all nodes, and skipping (`continue`) each iteration where the node type is not `TEX_IMAGE`.